# Zipping a Python Dictionary and List together

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Is it possible to Zip a python Dictionary and List together?

For Example:

```
dict = {'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':3}
num_list = [1, 2, 3]
zipped = zip(dict, num_list)
```

Then I'd like to do something like this:

```
for key, value, num_list_entry in zipped:
  print key
  print value
  print num_list_entry
```

I haven't found a solution for this, so I'm wondering how do I go about doing this?

Comment: Have you looked at what each item in `zipped` is? They don't have length three, so you can't unpack to three names like that.

Comment: **DO NOT** use dict as the name for the variable, use something like my_dict

Comment: it's bad practice to use the name "dict" for your dictionary... it shadows the real `dict`, which is a built-in function name

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `iteritems()`.

```
dictionary = {'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':3}
num_list = [1, 2, 3]
zipped = zip(dictionary.iteritems(), num_list)

for (key, value), num_list_entry in zipped:
    print key
    print value
    print num_list_entry
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm trying to do this in a django application, but the for loop doesn't seem to work in the template. Any ideas why?

Comment: In a django template you would do:
{% for dictionary, num_list_entry in zipped %}
  {% with key=dictionary.0 value=dictionary.1 %}
    {{key}}
    {{value}}
    {{num_list entry}}
  {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}

Comment: Usually, we want to do this sort of thing with an ordered dictionary. Giving an example with ordered dictionary would be equally useful.

Answer (score 6):

Note: do *not* shadow the built-in `dict`. This will one day come back to haunt you.

Now, as for your issue, simply use `dict.items`:

```
>>> d = {'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':'3'}
>>> num_list = [1, 2,3 ]
>>> for (key, value), num in zip(d.items(), num_list):
...     print(key)
...     print(value)
...     print(num)
...
A
1
1
C
3
2
B
2
3
>>>
```

Note: Dictionaries aren't ordered, so you have no guarantee on the order of the items when iterating over them.

Additional Note: when you iterate over a dictionary, it iterates over the keys:

```
>>> for k in d:
...     print(k)
...
A
C
B
```

Which makes this common construct:

```
>>> for k in d.keys():
...     print(k)
...
A
C
B
>>>
```

Redundant, and in Python 2, inefficient.