# Check dictionary keys for presence of list elements, create list of values if present, 'None' otherwise

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Forgive the convoluted title, but I couldn't find a more elegant way to express the problem. The closet question I could locate [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41624308), but it doesn't quite get me there.

Assume a number of dictionaries of varying lengths:

```
dict_1 = {'A':4, 'C':5}
dict_2 = {'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':3}
dict_3 = {'B':6}
```

The common denominator for these dictionaries is that they all share the keys on this list:

```
my_keys= ['A','B','C']
```

but some are missing one or more of the keys.

The intent is to create a list of lists, where each list element is a list of all the existing values in each dictionary, or 'None' where a specific key isn't present. They keys themselves, being identical across all dictionaries, can be disregarded.

So in this case, the expected output is:

```
    final_list = 
    [[4,"None",5],
    [1,2,3],
    ["None",6,"None"]]
```

I'm not sure exactly how to approach it. You could start with each element in `my_keys`, and check its presence against each key in each dictionary; if the relevant dict has the key, the value of that key is appended to a temporary list; otherwise, 'None' is appended. Once the `my_keys` are all iterated over, the temp list is appended to a final list and the cycle start again.

To me at least, it's easier said than done. I tried quite a few things (which I won't bother to post because they didn't get even close). So I was wondering if there is an elegant approach to the problem.

Comment: The second to last paragraph sounds like a reasonable algorithm. What exactly was the problem when you tried to write some for loops and dictionary lookups to implement it?

Comment: @mkrieger1 - I got tangled in my own shoelaces, running nested `for` loops (and probably not enough coffee...), while what I really needed is a simple solution like that below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dict.get` can return a default value (for example, `None`). If we take your examples:

```
dict_1 = {'A':4, 'C':5}
dict_2 = {'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':3}
dict_3 = {'B':6}
my_keys= ['A','B','C']
```

Then `dict_1.get('B', None)` is the way to make sure we get a default `None` value. We can loop across all keys the same way:

```
def dict_to_list(d, keys):
    return [d.get(key, None) for key in keys]
```

Example:

```
>>> dict_to_list(dict_1, my_keys)
[4, None, 5]
>>> dict_to_list(dict_2, my_keys)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> dict_to_list(dict_3, my_keys)
[None, 6, None]
```

EDIT: `None` is the default argument even if it's not explicitly specified, so `dict_1.get('B')` would work just as well as `dict_1.get('B', None)`

Comment: Wow, talk about short and elegant! Thanks for that. I feel embarrassed for not having figured it out myself. But, yes, that gets the job done!